# give a value to captured group and use it in replace function of intellij

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

I'm trying to translate some of my methods and field names with regex in intellij. In particular I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
public class SomeClass {
  
  private String italianNameField;

  public void setItalianNameField(String italianNameField) {
    this.italianNameField = italianNameField;
  }

}
```

becomes

```
public class SomeClass {
  
  private String englishNameField;

  public void setEnglishNameField(String englishNameField) {
    this.englishNameField = englishNameField;
  }

}
```

so far my regex look like this:

`(public void set)ItalianFieldName(\(String )italianFieldName(\) \{ this.)italianFieldName( = )italianFieldName(; \})` and in the replace field I put `$1EnglishNameField$2englishNameField$3englishNameField$4englishNameField$5`

I would like to know if it's possible to do create a variable and use that, something like this:

```
var1 = englishName
public void set\Lvar1(String var1) { this.var1 = var1; }
```

and possibly change the field name at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach to achieve the desired result:

- Point the cursor at `private String italianNameField` and press `Shift + F6` to invoke refactoring action:
  [image]
- rename it to `englishNameField` and press Enter
- additional dialog for Setters/Getters refactorings will be shown automatically:
  [image]
- click OK

Answer (score 0):

You can replace:

```
italiannamefield\b
```

...with:

```
englishNameField
```

`\b` means a word boundary. IntelliJ matches regex case-insensitively by default; it will also handle the casing part correctly for you with the *Preserve case* option (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>) enabled.

Regex matching affects everything, from code to comment and text. However, do note that this is error-prone and is not recommended unless you're willing to manually check all replacements.

Try it:

[image: Replace italiannamefield\b]
[image: ...with englishNameField]